# Passing form values via POST method in form Update

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

I've a sql database table which I'm displaying on a webpage using HTML tables. The last column of the table is an "edit" option via which I wish to prompt the user to update the data.

For this I want to pass those data values for the row ID which was selected by the user to edit.

My display table has the following code

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetched_value, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            echo
                "<tr>
                    <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['email_id']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['mobile_number']}</td>;
                    echo '<td><button id="edit_button" name="edit_button" type="submit" style="border:0; background:transparent;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#006600;"></i></button></td>';
                echo "</tr>\n";
        }
?>
```

where,

```
<?php $fetched_value = mysql_query( $fetch_query, $conn ); ?>
```

Please note that at the end of every row I've an edit button, which I want to use for further processing.

I want to call (via `POST` method) a local php file, say `update-data.php`, in which there will be code to accept the `POST`ed data, display the table and also to **prefill** the form spaces.

However I'm unable to pass the data to this update PHP file using the `POST` method.

Can you please suggest a way to pass those particular data values for which the update link was clicked?

Comment: There are many wrong things with your code.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes thank you. But could you be a little more specific? The data is displaying as expected in my page. (I know mysql functions are deprecated. I only use them to make my transition to mysqli smoother.)(I'm a beginner)

Comment: Your first `echo` you aren't closing the string encapsulation. If you are going to use a `submit` button for each field you need a `form` for each that it is submitting. You could just use a link that loads the edit page. `<a href="page.php?id={$id}&action=edit">Edit</a>`.

Answer (score 1):

As chris85 pointed out, GET would be your choice, unless you are willing to wrap every row in a 'FORM' or to use 'JS'.

**GET**:

Generate links instead of a buttons: `<a href="update-data.php?id={$row[id]}&action=edit">Edit</a>`

You can make them look like buttons via CSS.

You can fetch the rest of the data to prefil form in update-data.php or send it expanding your GET query, but be aware: if there is any kind of sensitive data you wish to pass, sending it all via GET - IS NOT THE WAY.

**FORM**:

Wrap every row in a form :

```
echo
                "
                <form method="post" action="update-data.php">
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="{$row['name']}">
                <input type="hidden" name="email_id" value="{$row['email_id']}">
                <input type="hidden" name="mobile_number" value="{$row['mobile_number']}">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{$row['id']}">
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit">
                <tr>
                    <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['email_id']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['mobile_number']}</td>;
                    echo '<td><button id="edit_button" name="edit_button" type="submit" style="border:0; background:transparent;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#006600;"></i></button></td>';
                echo "</tr>\n</form>";
```

Here you would would have all the values sent. As in GET option, whatever you do you have to send a unique row identifier (assuming you will want to update the entry or do anything else with it), so i assumed you have an auto increment column 'id' as it is the most common thing imo. Change it your unique row identifier if its not the case.

**JS**:

Third option is to add an `onclick` attribute to your submit button linking to a js function that submits a hidden/genereated form filling the field as in example above. This might look something like this:

```
<?php   echo
                "
                <tr>
                    <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['email_id']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['mobile_number']}</td>;
                    echo '<td><button id="{$row['id']}" name="edit_button" onclick="send(this)" style="border:0; background:transparent;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#006600;"></i></button></td>';
                echo "</tr>\n";
?>
    <scritp>

    function send(button) {
        var form = $('            
        <form method="post" action="update-data.php">                
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + button.id + '">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit"></form>
    ');
        $('body').append(form);
        form.submit();
    }
    </scirpt>
```

Hope you will find at least something useful here. I'm not really an expert:D yet :D

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this `echo '<td><button onclick="editData()" type="button" style="border:0; background:transparent;"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#006600;"></i></button></td>';` . So then you can pass the data in editData() by ajax. Goodluck